# Using Sass with Django

Tags: django, sass, node-sass

Im looking for a reasonably simple toolset and workflow for incorporating Sass into my Django projects. Im predominantly backend focused and have just started investigating Sass, so bear with me.

My initial idea was to keep things simple by just using [node-sass](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) without trying to incorporate Gulp, django-pipeline or anything else initially.

My Django apps are usually structured such that I create a `static/app/css` folder in each app. One option I guess would be to now create an additional folder per app for scss files, ie: `static/app/scss`. The problem there would be that when running collectstatic in production, the scss files will be gathered as well. So should the scss files for each app be kept somewhere else? (I guess it doesn't really matter if the scss files are included when collectstatic runs?)

Next, outside of my Django project folders I would create a folder to install `node-sass` since I wouldn't want to install it globally and I don't want the `node-modules` folder inside my Django project or inside source control.

I guess the node-modules folder can be thought of like using a python virtualenv instead of installing packages globally?

Next, inside my Django project somewhere (not sure where?) I would have the `package.json` file containing a scripts section for every scss file I want compiled to css, eg:

```
"scripts": {
    "compile:sass": "node-sass app1/static/app1/scss/style.scss app1/static/app1/css/style.css",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass app2/static/app2/scss/style.scss app2/static/app2/css/style.css",
    "compile:sass": "node-sass app3/static/app3/scss/style.scss app3/static/app3/css/style.css"
}
```

Lastly, I would just run compile:sass with the watch flag to constantly compile any files I work on and put them in the correct folders.

So my questions are, is the above setup a good approach (at least initially if im not ready to add yet another tool like Gulp etc to the mix)?

Also, how will I run compile:sass considering my package.json file will be in the Django project somewhere and the `node-modules` folder containing the `node-sass` installation will be somewhere else.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. Put `package.json` at the root of your project, and keep `node_modules` in that directory. Just ignore the directory in your `.gitignore`

Comment: Also, it's a bit weird that you have so many `compile:sass` scripts in your `package.json`. Why not just make a single `.scss` file that `import`s all of your separate `.scss` files and compile that one?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've now got what seems to be a reasonable project layout and workflow with node-sass. package.json and node_modules (git ignored) in the root. node-sass running constantly with the watch flag. Seems good enough for now. I'll also just use imports instead of multiple scripts where appropriate.

Comment: Yes common pattern (or at least what I use), is to have a `/static/styles/sass` directory with `app.scss`. That directory has a subdirectory `pages`, in which `_home_page.scss` etc live. `app.scss` contains `@import "pages/home_page";` along with all your other "page" sass files.

Comment: Then compile `app.scss` to `/static/styles/css`

Answer (score 1):

I help maintain node-sass, so I won't say not to use it. There is an alternate libsass-python that you might want to look at if you're working with Python though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [django-sass-processor](https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor) package. It's simple to configure and use. I've used it a few times and have had good experiences with it. The package abstracts away Gulp, so you don't have to worry about it and streamlines the whole process.

Here's a tutorial on [how to integrate django-sass-processor](https://engineertodeveloper.com/how-to-easily-use-sass-scss-with-django/) into a Django project.